# Filter XML / HTML Code tags with RegEx

Tags: xml, regex, perl

following scenario:

Given is a XML-like document:

```
<Root>  
<NotNeededTag style="color: #ABCDEF">With needed Text</NotNeededTag>  
Text here <Break/>  
<Bold> with bolded text </Bold>  
Next text <Italic> It's a kind <Bold> OF </Bold> M A G I C  
</Root>
```

---

My aim is it to filter all tags which are not Bold, Italic and Break, but the text in the not-needed-tags should be retain:

```
With needed Text  
Text here <Break/>  
<Bold> with bolded text </Bold>  
Next text <Italic> It's a kind <Bold> OF </Bold> M A G I C
```

Is this possible to realize it with regular expressions?

kind regards
sb

Comment: Bad idea, and, Exact duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: No, just a bad question. He does not want to parse it, but filter tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
$_ = <main::DATA>;

s/<\/?(?:(?!bold|italic|break).)*?\/?>//ig;

print $_;

__DATA__
<Root>
<NotNeededTag style="color: #ABCDEF">With needed Text</NotNeededTag>
Text here <Break/>
<Bold> with bolded text </Bold>
Next text <Italic> It's a kind <Bold> OF </Bold> M A G I C
```

***Output:***

```
With needed Text  
Text here <Break/>  
<Bold> with bolded text </Bold>  
Next text <Italic> It's a kind <Bold> OF </Bold> M A G I C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse HTML with RegExps and you should not do it for XML either.

But having a valid XML document, you can use Regexes to replace tags. Valid means in here that `<` and `>` are escaped where not belonging to a tag. Then it should be possible to delete everything that matches

```
/<\/?(?!(Bold|Italic|Break)\s*\/?>)[^\s]+?>/
```

I'm not familiar with perl, but I'm sure you can adapt that regex.

Comment: Actually, `>` does not need to be escaped for the XML to be well-formed. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax: *"The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string " &gt; ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either " &gt; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section."* This may, or may not be nitpicking: `<script>if( 1 > 0) { alert( "booh!"); }</script>` is  well-formed for example .

Comment: OK, then it gets more difficult to find the tags.